# How to make angular refresh screen in the middle of execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, page-refresh

I have a little angular html in a third's page.

Everything works fine, the code works fine, the directives work fine (except "ng-show" which never works, but that doesn't matter here).

But I have a heavy code that runs in a button click (with `ng-click`). During the execution everything freezes, ok, that's expected.

But I wish very much to make an "img" appear during the execution, but it seems nothing is updated during the code (everything is perfectly updated after the code, but not **during** the code).

How can I "refresh" the angular html "during" the execution of the code in "ng-click"?

I've tried "$scope.apply()" and "$scope.digest()", but both cause some weird errors in the console....

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to the answers below: The errors were indeed because the "apply/digest" was already in progress. By using the assynchronous methods shown, I can use "apply" without problems.

Comment: This question as asked is too vague to provide a solid answer, and seems to hint at some misunderstandings related to the angular framework.  In particular, it's impossible to troubleshoot "some weird errors", but very possible to troubleshoot an *actual* error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way JavaScript works in a browser environment is that one block of javascript is executed until it is finished, the browser does not render intermediate results regardless if you use AngularJS or vanilla JavaScript.

#### Example

Let's assume you do heavy lifting on 10.000 data entries and want to show a progress bar:

```
startButton.onclick = function onStartClick() {
  var progressbar = document.getElementById('progressbar');
  progressbar.style.width = "0";

  // process 100000 entries, update progress bar between
  for (var n = 0; n < 100000; y++) {
    doSomethingWithEntryNumber(n);
    progressbar.style.width = (n / 100000) + "%";
  }
}
```

It will not update the progressbar `div` in the browser as might be intended, but will freeze the browser until `onDivClick` is finished. This is no different for AngularJS, where processing lots of data will not update your UI.

To process a large amount of data, you need to split the work and use any kind of "future"/"promise"/"delay" technique - for this example:

```
startButton.onclick = function onStartClick() {
  var progressbar = document.getElementById('progressbar');
  progressbar.style.width = "0";

  // process 100000 entries in 1000 entry batches, update progress bar between
  function processBatch(batch) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      doSomethingWithEntryNumber(batch*1000 + i);
    }
    // update progressbar
    progressbar.style.width = (batch / 1000) + "%";
    if (batch < 99) {
      // continue work after browser has updated UI
      setTimeout(processBatch.bind(this, batch + 1), 10);
    }
  }
  processBatch(0);
}
```

This way the browser can render UI changes, the user can scroll, etc. while you are still able to process your 100000 data entries.

In respect to "showing an image during the process", you would show the image, then `setTimeout` to do your work delayed, when your work is finished remove the image and set your data to the `$scope`.

Comment: Thanks for accepting as answer - that is kind of a rarity ;)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot refresh the HTML "during" the execution, as a web page in mono-threaded, which means when the CPU is computing, nothing else can be done. (Technically web workers can help forking multiple threads but really, you do not need that).

So what you want on click is say, enable an image, then wait for angular to update the DOM with that image, and then run your heavy code.

To achieve that you need to use the `$timeout` service, this way:

```
$scope.onClick = function() {
  // Set the model to display an image
  $scope.displayImage = true;
  // Wait for angular to digest the current cycle and update the DOM
  $timeout(function() {
    // Do heavy stuff, and at the bottom of the code update the model to hide the image
    $scope.doHeavyStuff();
    $scope.displayImage = false;
  });
}
```

In your HTML you simply need

```
<img ng-show = "displayImage" src = "some_url">
<div ng-hide = "displayImage"> Heavy stuff done :) </div>
```

Now if you have a problem with ng-show at this step, please open a different question.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing an ng-show on an image? You could use a div that takes up the entire section you wish to show an image with

```
<div ng-show="loading" class="some-class-to-display-image"></div>
```

then in your js turn `$scope.loading = true;` while you're processing / making calls / etc. You can use a promise and use a `.finally()` on your requests and set `$scope.loading = false;` to stop the animation.

Comment: `ng-show` never works for me, it always shows, no matter whether the value is true or not. (`ng-if` works, though, but it doesn't update **during** the execution)

Comment: @Daniel try class="ng-hide" ng-show="expression", don't forget ng-hide class

Comment: @Daniel ng-show works, you might just not be using it correctly. Unless you're in some janky version of angular that I've never seen/heard of/used :P 

What are you trying to use for your NG show? It has to be something that evaluates to true/false. 

Best way to describe a promise: http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Essentially you'd be using a .then() to tell angular what you want it to do after your request. I'd recommend putting any logic for show/hide into .finally() though.

Comment: Well, I tried everything, really, nothing works. It should work exactly like "ng-if", right? (Yes, ng-if works fine).

Comment: It can provide the same functionality as ng-if, but it's sort of pointless when you have ng-show at your disposal which does exactly what you need. Give me an example of your code and I'll see if I can get it to work.

Comment: This works: `<span id="img-container" ng-if="filterData.isLoading">{{...}}</span>`         

This doesn't: `<span id="img-container" ng-show="filterData.isLoading">{{...}}</span>` --- (yes, I tried it with the `class="ng-hide"` too)

Comment: @Daniel so you're setting filterData.isLoading to a boolean "true" when you want it to show, correct? I've had very consistent results with ng-show and have interchanged it with ng-if in very specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the code you want to execute first in a $scope.apply() should work unless your getting a "$digest already in progress" error which occurs as only one digest cycle can be run at a time.

If that's the case you could try wrapping the code you want to execute after the loading image is displayed in a $timeout or $evalAsync(Angular v1.2.x & above) which will make sure the 2 digest cycles don't collide i.e.

```
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        //display loading image code
    });
    //Other code
```

or

```
    //display loading image code
    $scope.$evalAsync(function () {
        //Other code
    });
```